# Certain Files getting corrupted by SQL Server FileStream

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, filestream

I am saving files to a SQL server 2008 (Express) database using FILESTREAM, the trouble I'm having is that certain files seem to be getting corrupted in the process.

For example if I save a word or excel document in one of the newer formats (docx, or xslx) then when I try to open the file I get an error message saying that the data is corrupted and would I like word/excel to try and recover it,  If I click yes office is able to 'recover' the data and opens the file in compatibility mode.

However if i zip the file first then after extracting the contents I'm able to open the file without a problem. Strangely If I save an mp3 file to the database then I have the reverse issue, I can open the file no problem, but If I saved a zipped version of the mp3 I can't even extract the contents of that zip.  When I tried to save a pdf or power-point file I ran into similar problems (the pdf i could only read if I zipped it first, and the ppt I couldn't read at all).

Update: here's my code that I'm using to write to the database and to read

To write to the database:

```
SQL = "SELECT Attachment.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM Activity " +
               "WHERE RowID = CAST(@RowID as uniqueidentifier)";
           transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

           command.Transaction = transaction;
           command.CommandText = SQL;
           command.Parameters.Clear();
           command.Parameters.Add(rowIDParam);

           SqlDataReader readerFS = null;
           readerFS= command.ExecuteReader();

   string path = (string)readerFS[0].ToString();
   byte[] context = (byte[])readerFS[1];
   int length = context.Length;

   SqlFileStream targetStream = new SqlFileStream(path, context, FileAccess.Write);

         int blockSize = 1024 * 512; //half a megabyte
            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            targetStream.Close();
            sourceStream.Close();
            readerFS.Close();
            transaction.Commit();
```

And to read:

```
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlTransaction transaction = null;

        try
        {
            connection = getConnection();
            connection.Open();
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            SQL = "SELECT Attachment.PathName(), + GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM Activity"
          +  " WHERE ActivityID = @ActivityID";


            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ActivityID", activity.ActivityID));

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            string path = (string)reader[0];
            byte[] context = (byte[])reader[1];
            int length = context.Length;
            reader.Close();

            SqlFileStream sourceStream = new SqlFileStream(path, context, FileAccess.Read);

            int blockSize = 1024 * 512; //half a megabyte
            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
           List<byte> attachmentBytes = new List<byte>();

            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                foreach (byte b in buffer)
                {
                    attachmentBytes.Add(b);
                }

            }

            FileStream outputStream = File.Create(outputPath);

            foreach (byte b in attachmentBytes)
            {
                 byte[] barr = new byte[1];

                 barr[0] = b;

                 outputStream.Write(barr, 0, 1);
            }

            outputStream.Close();
            sourceStream.Close();
            command.Transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Could be that the corruption occurs in your client handling of the inserts? Eg. premature truncation, or use use a varchar() vs. nvarchar() argument type passed to SQL, or char vs. binary? Woudl you care to post the code you use to upload the content into the filestreams and the code used to access the filestream?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my question with my code. 

I'm not sure what you mean by using the wrong type argument, the field in sql-server is of type Varbinary(max) FILESTREAM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your read code is incorrect:

```
  while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            foreach (byte b in buffer)
            {
                attachmentBytes.Add(b);
            }

        }
```

If the bytesRead is less than buffer.Length, you still add the entire buffer to the attachementBytes. Thus, you always corrupt the document returned by adding any garbage in the end of the last buffer post bytesRead.

Other than that, allow me to have a really WTF moment. Reading a stream as a `List<byte>` ?? C'mon! First, I don't see the reason why you need to read into an intermediate in-memory storage to start with. You can simply read buffer by buffer and write each buffer straight into the outputStream. Second, if you *must* use an intermediate in-memory storage, use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), not a `List<byte>`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

I changed it so that I'm writing directly from the input stream to the output stream.

Comment: And ignoring, for the moment, that it throws away the first buffer.length of bytes during read also (bytesRead = ..., while (bytesRead > 0), bytesRead = ...)

Comment: Interestingly I was recently reading through [Jon Skeet's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/Jon-Skeet) [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/) and he mentions (page 86) how with generics in many ways a `List<byte>` actually behaves like a `MemoryStream`. I'm not saying it was the right choice in this instance, and the only thing I can really say in my defense here is that when I wrote it I was a lot more inexperienced and if I recall correctly I based part of my original code off a snippet I read online that used a list.

Comment: @Jack nice comeback :)

Comment: Thanks, I was always a bit embarrassed of this question (well that aspect), so it's kind of stuck in my head...

Answer (score 2):

I had the [exact problem](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2010/02/18/why-do-excel-2007-prompt-for-repair-when-opening-a-document-stored-in-sql-server-2008-filestream-column.aspx) a few months back and figured out that I was adding an extra byte at the end of the file when reading it from FILESTREAM.

Comment: I read through your post, and I found it informative as I was wondering why I only had a problem with particular file formats (and particularly why the old office formats didn't seem to be getting corrupted).

Comment: Having the same issue, but the blog post is no longer working. Can you add some more details in whats going on here and how you fixed it?